# Linq: How to group with index from object data

Tags: c#, linq

I have an example data

```
---------------------------------------
   Name    |  Old  |  Year  |  Address
---------------------------------------
1. Ann     |  24   |  1990  |  Address1
---------------------------------------
2. Billy   |  22   |  1992  |  Address2
---------------------------------------
3. Chris   |  24   |  1990  |  Address3
---------------------------------------
4. Dean    |  23   |  1991  |  Address4
---------------------------------------
```

Data will display on grid like that with header columns: Name, Old, Year, Address

Data has type: IList. Each item has type: object[]

If I group Name, it turns to:

```
---------------------------------------
   Name    |  Old  |  Year  |  Address
---------------------------------------
1. Ann     |  24   |  1990  |  Address1
---------------------------------------
2. Billy   |  22   |  1992  |  Address2
---------------------------------------
3. Chris   |  24   |  1990  |  Address3
---------------------------------------
4. Dean    |  23   |  1991  |  Address4
---------------------------------------
```

If I group by Year, it turns to:

```
------------------------------------------------------
   Name         |  Old  |  Year  |  Address
------------------------------------------------------
1. Ann, Chris   |  24   |  1990  |  Address1, Address3
------------------------------------------------------
2. Billy        |  22   |  1992  |  Address2
------------------------------------------------------
3. Dean         |  23   |  1991  |  Address4
------------------------------------------------------
```

So the current group which support by LINQ, it can't do that.
My way is: group by Year first, after that, I manipulate data in manually.
I have list index that user want to group by: IList, in this case will be 2.

Because my data have IList and each of them is object[], I wrote a class like this:

```
        class GroupComparer : IEqualityComparer<object>
        {
            private IList<int> indexList;

            public GroupComparer(IList<int> indexList)
            {
                this.indexList = indexList;    
            }

            #region IEqualityComparer<object> Members

            public bool Equals(object x, object y)
            {
                object[] arrX = (object[])x;
                object[] arrY = (object[])y;

                bool isEqual = true;

                foreach (var item in this.indexList)
                {
                    if(arrX[item] != arrY[item])
                    {
                        isEqual = false;
                    }
                }

                return isEqual;
            }

            public int GetHashCode(object obj)
            {
                int hCode = 0;
                object[] arrObj = (object[])obj;

                foreach (var item in this.indexList)
                {
                    hCode ^= (int)arrObj[item];
                }

                return hCode.GetHashCode();
            }

            #endregion
        }
```

And the place consumed it:

```
    IList<object> data = ConvertToArrayObject(strDatas);

    IList<int> index = new List<int>();
    index.Add(2);

    var groups = data.GroupBy(p => p, new GroupComparer(index));
```

But the result is not group.

May you show me how to group by index like that?

Best regard

Comment: Do you actually group your data or do you order it? Also: Why don't you parse your data to int-values and order by this?

Comment: _"So the current group which support by LINQ, it can't do that"_ What can't LINQ do and why? What is the desired output?

Comment: Serv: data type is dynamic, maybe that column is DateTime, maybe int, or string... I grouping, not order.
TimSchmelter: the group normal can't do, I means I write class inherits IEqualityComparer. The desire output is the third data table. But, currently I only group, desire output is group. but it's not group after run that.

Comment: +1 for attentive question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I answer this question by my article:
[When LINQ execute query](https://medium.com/@taiphatlam/when-linq-execute-query-98fcbc6306d8?source=latest&)